# ngx-loading Toggling from another component

Tags: angular

I'm using [ngx-loading](https://github.com/Zak-C/ngx-loading) and want to be able to trigger it's showing/hiding from children components. Here is what I currently have:

**App.Component**

```
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  public loading = false;

  constructor() { }

  loader() {
    this.loading = !this.loading;
    console.log(this.loading);
  }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
import { AppComponent} from '../app/app-component';
import { MyService } from '../service/my-service';

@Component({
  selector:'child-component',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  providers: [AppComponent, MyService]
})

export class ChildComponent implments OnInit {
  constructor(private loader: AppComponent, private service: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData();
  }


  getData() {
    this.loader.loader();
    this.service.getDataFromService().then(res => {
      this.myModel = res;
      this.loader.loader();
    }
  }
}
```

If I check my logs this.loader is toggle from true to false but the ngx-loading component isn't.  If I set the initial value of loading in app.component ngx-loading displays but wont hide. So I know that the loader is working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that change detection doesn't run. I have created a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Chg3VAAAWulT2IOjtBP5?p=preview) to make it work. I would recommend you to use EventEmmiter(Output). The main idea is after the promise is finished, you run setTimeout to trigger changeDetection.

```
this.getData().then(() => {          
   setTimeout(() => {
      this.load.emit()
   })
```

Comment: Thanks @alexKhymenko